# Rails how to beautify this block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

kinda new to Rails.

How would you simplify, beautify this method:

```
def find_index
   index = 0
   @ipn.each {|p|
       index = 4 if p = "new" #this is just a dummy line
   }
   index
end
```

As you can see, it's ugly. How can I remove the index definition at the top and the index at the bottom to return - The Ruby way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this method:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index

```
def find_index
  @ipn.find_index{|p| p == "new" }
end
```

I also change the variable name '@ipn' to '@ipns', since it seems to be an enumerable.

And to avoid confusion, I might rename the method to 'find_ipn_index', so it looks like this:

```
def find_ipn_index
  @ipns.find_index{|p| p == "new" }
end
```

Or, if self.ipns is available, don't define a new method at all for this, just call:

```
self.ipns.find_index{|p| p == "new" }
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Yes I see where you are going with this. But what if  I simply wanted to assign a variable inside a block and return that variable? Like this:http://blakesmith.me/2010/08/16/the-rails-returning-statement.html but without the returning method.

Comment: Please ask another, or edit your question, if this is really what you want to know, and not how to beautify the block above.  Otherwise, you are asking me to put an answer in a comment, which is hard to do without code snippets, or most formatting.

Comment: If you want to use it outside the block, then a variable assigned in a block, has to be defined outside the block, so you won't be able to get rid of 'index = ' something.  If all you want to do is return that value, you don't need to assign it, it just needs to be returned by the block, and that is why returning is useful.